# How to get element id respect to style class using Mootools

Tags: mootools

Consider following structure

```
<div class="form-final-label" id="1_30_17-label">
<label class="required" for="1_30_17">Business/Store Name</label>
</div>
<div class="form-final-label" id="1_32_17-label">
<label for="1_32_17">First Name</label>
</div>
<div class="form-final-label" id="1_34_17-label">
<label for="1_34_17">Last Name</label>
</div>
```

How can I get all label's `for` attribute with respect to class required using Mootools.ie, here I would like to retrieve 1_30_17.

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://mootorial.com/wiki/mootorial/05-utilities/00-selectors) you should be able to do something like:

```
$('1_30_17-label').getElements('label[for=1_30_17]');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Here all number are dynamic. We can't guess. Actually, I need to get these numbers according to class='required'

Comment: $$('label.required') to return all elements with the required class, then for each of those returned items do the call .getAttribute("for") https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute

Comment: `document.getElements("label.required").get("for")` will return an array of the for= values.